# Maven test dependency not being found

Tags: maven, maven-2, build, dependencies, powermock

I'm declaring a test dependency on powermock with easymock bundled in.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-easymock-release-full</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.12</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I run `mvn test`, the test src claims to be able to find `org.powermock` but not `org.easymock`, despite it being included in the above dependency.

I wondered whether it was a problem due to transitivity of the test scope, so i tried compile scope also (as the documentation `http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html` mentions that the compile dependencies are available at test time) without any luck.

I've also tried using a bundled jar instead of pom, to no avail. I realise i could declare the dependencies separately (ie separate dependencies for powermock and easymock) but for my purposes i'm restricted to having just the one dependency including all necessary test libs.

Comment: Have you checked the public repositories that you're using to see if the missing dependencies are there (in your case, org.easymock)? I've had issues where a dependent library has been updated to include dependencies that haven't been released to a public directory, and then have to go and find these and add them to my local / our internal repositories.

Comment: Good idea, but it seems to call powermock-api-easymock which calls easymock (org.easymock) which all seem to exist on Maven Central.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracing this back to the [powermock parent pom](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/powermock/powermock/1.4.12/powermock-1.4.12.pom) I see that the easymock dependency is marked "provided."

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
      <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Looks like powermock is expecting its clients (you in this case) to supply the easymock jars.

Comment: Ah, that being the case i think my objective becomes to find out whether *any* of the central dependencies will pull everything in or not. Thank you.

Comment: I think maybe you can delegate all build/test work from IDE to Maven so that it would compile/run test correctly?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [powermock-easymock-release-full POM](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.powermock%7Cpowermock-easymock-release-full%7C1.4.12%7Cpom), it does not depend on easymock (ie easymock does not appear in the `powermock-easymock-release-full` dependencies). So you'll have to add another dependency to easymock, dependending on the test engine you're using (JUnit or TestNG): http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.powermock%22%20AND%20%22easymock%22

Comment: But it does depend on powermock-api-easymock which itself depends on org.easymock:easymock, should that not be just as good?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you're right. Could you please add the error output ?

Comment: Hi, it's really just "package org.easymock does not exist" and "symbol not found" - i can add a more detailed log later if that doesn't shed any light. I'm wondering if easymock doesn't end up in the classpath - i don't see an easymock jar which i somewhat expected

Comment: try a `mvn dependency:tree` and look for your missing dependency.